# How to build the multiplataform docker image on macos?

Tags: linux, docker

I tried building the docker image on a mac with multiplataform but if failed.

Command I ran:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t brandojazz/lean-dojo:latest --push .
```

**Logs in Debug Mode**

```bash
❯ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t brandojazz/lean-dojo:latest --push .
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                     docker:desktop-linux
ERROR: Multi-platform build is not supported for the docker driver.
Switch to a different driver, or turn on the containerd image store, and try again.
Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/build-multi-platform/
```

The docker file is:

```
# Use a specific version of kitware/cmake as the base image
FROM kitware/cmake:ci-clang_cxx_modules-x86_64-2023-02-15

# Install required packages: 'which', GMP library development files, Python3, and pip
RUN yum -y install which gmp-devel python3 python3-pip
# Create a symbolic link for python3 as /usr/bin/python for compatibility
RUN ln -s $(which python3) /usr/bin/python
# Install Python packages: toml for TOML file parsing, loguru for logging, tqdm for progress bars
RUN pip3 install toml loguru tqdm

# Set the environment variable ELAN_HOME to store Elan's installation
ENV ELAN_HOME="/.elan"
# Add ELAN_HOME/bin to the PATH for easier access to Elan's binaries
ENV PATH="${ELAN_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# Download and execute Elan's installation script in silent mode with auto-approval
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanprover/elan/master/elan-init.sh -sSf | bash -s -- -y

# Change permissions to allow writing in the /.elan directory
RUN chmod -R a+w /.elan

# Set the working directory to /workspace for the container
WORKDIR /workspace
# Change permissions to allow writing in the /workspace directory
RUN chmod -R a+w /workspace
```

I also tried building it directly with more standard commands but due to `FROM kitware/cmake:ci-clang_cxx_modules-x86_64-2023-02-15` it didn't work in mac m1 max e.g.,

```bash
# Build the Image
docker build -t brandojazz/lean-dojo:latest .

# Push the Image to a Docker Registry
docker push brandojazz/lean-dojo:latest

# Start the Docker Container, -d, it runs the container in the background 
docker run -d --name lean-dojo-container brandojazz/lean-dojo:latest
# docker run -it --name lean-dojo-container brandojazz/lean-dojo:latest bash

# Attach to the running Docker container via a terminal CLI bash
docker exec -it lean-dojo-container bash
```

but what what I want is the **multiplataform** install to work.

---

ref:

- https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/
- LeanDojo for Lean 4 python env: https://github.com/lean-dojo/LeanDojo/issues/137

Comment: Did you perform the steps listed in the docker link? The error message suggests one of the steps was missed. Please include each of the commands run and their output.